# Cropping an image without reducing it's pixel

Tags: image, matlab

[image]

I want to remove the objects attached to the image's sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this line ...

```
image = imclearborder(image);
```

Comment: It won't hamper the image quality or anything ? @KaziZiaulHassan

Comment: You first try and see whether it does or not.